# Is it possible to use external control elements with an embedded Google Slides presentation?

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

I'm going to be working on a project that involves embedded Google Slides presentations, and I haven't been able to find any information regarding whether or not it is possible to use external HTML elements as controls (play, next slide, previous slide, etc.) for a presentation or if I'm stuck with the default controls in the iframe. Anyone have experience with this?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40786486/control-google-docs-embedded-viewer-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Due to the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), this will be unable to be done.*

#### More Information:

Embedding a Google Slides presentation in an HTML page will require using some sort of object like an iframe which is going to be subject to the same-origin policy restrictions.

In practice, this means that if you have a page embedded inside another, they can not interact with one another unless they have the same origin.

As per the MDN documentation about the same-origin policy:

[image]

That is to say, unless the Slides file and the webpage are hosted on the same domain, no interaction between them will be able to be accomplished - this even includes Google Sites as Sites and Slides are hosted on different sub-domains (`https://sites.google.com/` and `https://docs.google.com/presentation/` respectively).

#### References:

- [Same-origin policy - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)
- [Same-origin police - Web security | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

---

#### Related Questions:

- [Open google document in a compact form / switching to a compact form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58292732)